How can I measure similarity between two graphs with identical topology but different edge weights
I have two graphs, G1 and G2, with exactly the same topology. Their only difference lies in the edge weights, which vary between 0 and 1.
How can I measure the similarity between G1 and G2 under these conditions?
I tried
(1) Cosine Similarity: I considered the edge weights as a vector and measured the similarity between two graphs using cosine similarity between these vectors.
(2) Euclidean Distance: Similar to (1), I thought of edge weights as a single vector and calculated the Euclidean distance to evaluate the similarity.
(3) Spectral Theory: I measured the similarity between graphs by comparing the eigenvalues of their Laplacian matrices.

Flattening the graph topology into vectors is, in my opinion, not the best idea because you lose a lot of information and your similarity becomes a measure of vectors in some vector space. So, (1) and (2) seem too ad hoc to me.
I do not have the time to write a full answer but consider instead the line graph $L$ of your $G_1,G_2$ and two sets of vertex labels given by the edge labels. Then, you could build a similarity notion based on ideas of transport of mass from optimal transport along the edges of $L$ subject to some cost function.

What problem are you trying to solve?  The way you measure distance will be heavily influenced by that...
